# matching linear array to a circular array and get resultant

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a logic and lot of trial and error code but not successful. Hence, seeking help from veterans.

1. There are two arrays with

```
Array no.1 ==> colors = Array("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "Green", "Green", "red", "red", "red", "red")
Array no.2 ==> color1 = Array(Array("blue", "src1"), Array("blue", "src2"), Array("red", "src3"), Array("red", "src4"), Array("Green", "src5"))
```

I want to match elements of array no.1 sequentially with array no.2 in circular fashion. So that
resultant output would be fresh "src" part each time i.e. take each element of 1st array and match with array two in circular fashion so that every time **next** 'src' is picked up - let it repeat but no the 'same' src everytime. I tried various versions not successful, but I could not make it to circulate and get result. Sort of challenge for me at least and not even ChatGPT could give satisfactory outputs hence those codes of chatgpt i am not posting here.

```
blue:src1,
blue:src2,
blue:src1,
blue:src2,
Green:src5,
Green:src5,
red:src3,
red:src4,
red:src3,
red:src4
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use `objDic1` to consolidate `color1` by color
- Use `objDic2` to record the pointer for each color

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim Colors, Color1, aVal
    Dim objDic1 as Object, objDic2 as Object 
    Dim i As Long, sVal As String, sKey As String
    Colors = Array("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "Green", "Green", "red", "red", "red", "red")
    Color1 = Array(Array("blue", "src1"), Array("blue", "src2"), Array("red", "src3"), Array("red", "src4"), Array("Green", "src5"))
    Set objDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Color1)
        sKey = Color1(i)(0)
        If Not objDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic1(sKey) = Color1(i)(1)
            objDic2(sKey) = 0
        Else
            objDic1(sKey) = objDic1(sKey) & "|" & Color1(i)(1)
        End If
    Next
    For i = 0 To UBound(Colors)
        sKey = Colors(i)
        If objDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            aVal = Split(objDic1(sKey), "|")
            sVal = aVal(objDic2(sKey))
            Debug.Print Colors(i), sVal
            If objDic2(sKey) = UBound(aVal) Then
                objDic2(sKey) = 0
            Else
                objDic2(sKey) = objDic2(sKey) + 1
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print Colors(i), "N/A"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
blue          src1
blue          src2
blue          src1
blue          src2
Green         src5
Green         src5
red           src3
red           src4
red           src3
red           src4
```

Comment: works like a charm !!! Thanks tested and functional. That is why i surrender to veterans.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a temporary sheet:

```
Sub Colors()
   Dim Colors, Color1, rng As Range, item, fnd As Range, newsheet As Worksheet
   Colors = Array("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "Green", "Green", "red", "red", "red", "red")
   Color1 = Array(Array("blue", "src1"), Array("blue", "src2"), Array("red", "src3"), Array("red", "src4"), Array("Green", "src5"))
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
   Set rng = Range("a1").Resize(UBound(Color1) - LBound(Color1) + 1, 2)
   rng.Value = Application.Index(Color1, 0)
   Set fnd = Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1)
   For Each item In Colors
      Set fnd = rng.Columns(1).Find(item, fnd, xlValues, xlWhole)
      Debug.Print fnd.Value, fnd.Next.Value
   Next item
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   newsheet.Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If users alter the order of items in the first array, the output will be affected. eg. `Colors = Array("blue", "Green", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "Green", "Green", "red", "red", "Green", "red")`

Comment: Result in this case will be: blue          src1,
Green         src5,
red           src3,
blue          src1,
blue          src2,
blue          src1,
Green         src5,
Green         src5,
red           src3,
red           src4,
Green         src5,
red           src3.
In my opinion, this is O.K.

Comment: @MGonet,thanks for your effort. But order is important as mentioned by Mr. taller..Thanks to both of you for taking interest and spending valued time. Much obliged.